# receive files from PC through the support of web

Tags: c#, mobile, ftp, websocket

I need to send files from PC to mobile through the support of www or gprs.
what i need to do is when a user copy a file from a flash drive or any other devices which needs to be delivered in the mobile. how could i do this? i need a brief explanation on how could i do it? I have no idea on how to develop this application please provide me the enough explanation.
your comments are highly appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: www and gprs don't really have much to do with each other... I think you first should make yourself clear what you want.

Comment: what i want to do is.. i need to capture a file while it is being copied or saved in the PC. and then i want to send that file to mobile automatically when the copying process/saving process finishes. the file has to be stored in mobile storage. how could i do this?

Comment: This totally depends on the OS used on that mobile phone.

Comment: what about windows mobile or android?

Comment: You can do this using Dropbox or similar service. Register there, install client apps on PC and mobile and it will sync the files between them

Comment: Nop. coz i need to develop my own since this is a part/module of my undergraduate project. It sud be filled to complete the system. i stuck in this point. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a system consisting of 3 parts:

1. PC application(C#) that will track changes in a local folder and upload new files to web-service via HTTP
2. Web service (ASP .NET or whatever else) that will accept files from (1) and store them. Or you can just store files on FTP
3. Mobile application that will periodically check new files on (2) and download them to phone

Comment: well, yeah my application consist of those three parts as @MadBender mentioned. then if i need the file to be delivered in mobile in the real time rather than periodically checking it. what should i? thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: Could any body suggest me some good articles or tutorials which i need to learn in terms of completing this proj.

Comment: how do i check for new files which are on users account automatically by using the mobile application? without specifying a time period to check it from users account.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using your mail id. Send a mail with attached file to yourself and download it on your mobile by opening your mail on your mobile.